# How to redirect a jsp page to the same page with an added parameter

Tags: jsp

Could you please help me with this.

I need to redirect a jsp page to the same jsp page after appending parameter to existing url on click of a button
for ex :-Suppose the page url is

```
http://localhost:8080/example.jsp
```

Now when user will click Submit button,it should get redirected to same page and after appending parameter to it.

```
http://localhost:8080/example.jsp?a="hello"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set form `action` to `example.jsp` and `method= "GET"`
Eg:

```
<form action="example.jsp" method="GET">
```

`GET` method will cause to append input data to url.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try with a **hidden input field** where name is `a` and value is `hello`.

Sample code:

```
<form action="example.jsp?a=hello" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" value="hello" name="a" /> 
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```